# Hive job running forever on reduce phase

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hadoop2, beeline

I am running a query on `60 GB dataset in Hive`. When i fire a query `270 mappers` will finish within 15 Mins, but when it comes to `reducer state to complete 0.01%` , its taking minimum 45 mins to 1hr. So the job is running like forever. Is there any way to fix

Comment: look there is some soume in join  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+JoinOptimization

Comment: how many reducers are running?

Comment: Total Reducers: 1033 and Running state: 267

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u use a combiner and partitioner?

1. Case
   You can use combiner which is a mini reduce phase.
   *For ex:* if your mapper producers 100 lines of data , and if you use combiner to perform aggregate on it..it would be reduced to one line and 1 line * 270(mappers) = 270 lines and that is fed as input.
2. Case:
   You can use partitioner to partition data based on a key(if unique) or value (in-range) like if value > 20 return 0;else return 1. By this we will have more reducers to process data.